# How can I unfollow everyone at once on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

Instead of manually unfollowing everyone by clicking on "Unfollow", is there a way to automatically unfollow everyone on Twitter?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to unfollow everyone on your Twitter account you have to use some third-party applications like [Twitter unfollow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/twitter-unfollow/mmbbkpclbfmdacknjehonbfcilcfnkmb?hl=el) (Chrome Extension) or alternatively through Chrome or FF Developer Tools.

### Using Chrome Extension

> [Twitter unfollow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/twitter-unfollow/mmbbkpclbfmdacknjehonbfcilcfnkmb?hl=el) (Chrome Extension)

### Using Chrome Developer Tools

There is also another smart and easy way of bulk unfollowing at once on Twitter using Chrome or FF Developer Tools

> 1. Open https://twitter.com/following
> 2. Scroll to **bottom** until **all** users that you follow are loaded (**important**)
> 3. Right-click on an empty area > Inspection
> 4. After opening Developer Tools press ESC once to open the Console (if needed)
> 5. In the Console box type the following code and press enter
>
>    `$('.button-text.unfollow-text').trigger('click')`
> 6. Voila ! Every single "Following" button now has been magically clicked like you had one thousand mouse clicks at once turning off all of your "Following"s

---

[image]

Comment: As long as Twitter doesn't mind you sending that many requests at the very same time. It might depend on actually how many persons you are following or maybe Twitter just doesn't care: I haven't tried it.

Comment: @JeromeJ limit is 10000/day afaik. First you get warning on your account then if you repeat offend you get banned.

Comment: @JeromeJ you made a good point. Indeed, it is unknown if twitter.com/following will trigger some strange behavior or reaction when  receiving 1.000 "Unfollowing" requests simultaneously through DOM manipulation. However if anything happens, you can always break your batch action in less "Unfollowing" actions each time.

Comment: @ardaozkal JeromeJ did not write about sending 10000 Follow's to Twitter users (in a day). Please read my comment to him and you will understand what he meant.